# Firebase Cloud Messaging não envia som na notificação

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Possuo dois aplicativos, quando acontece tal ação em um dos dois aplicativos, ele envia uma notificação via FCM, para o outro aplicativo, quando chega a notificação , só faz o barulho de notificação se o aplicativo estiver aberto , quando ele está fechado a notificação chega silenciosamente

Segue o código do aplicativo receptor das notificações:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle().equals("Entrega")) {
        showNotificacaoTeste(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}

private void showNotificacaoTeste(String body) {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 1 ,new Intent(),PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT );
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
    builder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Entrega")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(1,builder.build());
}

}
```

Código que envia a notificação para o outro aplicativo

```
 private void cancelarEntrega(String clienteId) {
    Token token = new Token(clienteId);

    Notification notification = new Notification("Entrega", "O entregador não aceitou a entrega");
    Sender sender = new Sender(token.getToken(), notification);

    mFCMService.sendMessage(sender)
            .enqueue(new Callback<FCMResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<FCMResponse> call, Response<FCMResponse> response) {
                    if (response.body().success == 1) {

                        finish();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<FCMResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
}
```

Model da notificação

```
public class Notification {

public String title;
public String body;

  public Notification(String title, String body) {
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
}
}
```

Model do Sender:

```
public class Sender {
public String to;
public Notification notification;

public Sender(String to, Notification notification) {
    this.to = to;
    this.notification = notification;
}

}
```

Comment: Você está mandando a mensagem do tipo data ou do tipo notification? Coloca também o código onde você envia a notificação.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta @KaduAmaral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tenho certeza, mas isso pode estar acontecendo por causa do tipo da mensagem, você está mandando uma notificação do tipo "*Notification*", isso faz com que ela [seja entregue direto para a "bandeja" de *push* do Android e não passa pela sua função `onMessageReceived`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=pt-br#notifications_and_data_messages).

```
| Estado do app  | Notificação        | Dados             | Ambos                           |
| -------------- | ------------------ | ----------------- | ------------------------------- |
| Primeiro plano | onMessageReceived  | onMessageReceived | onMessageReceived               |
| Segundo plano  | Bandeja do sistema | onMessageReceived | Notificação: bandeja do sistema |
```

Envie com o tipo data, na sua classe Sender:

```
public Sender(String to, Notification notification) {
    this.to = to;
    this.data = notification; // <<-- Coloque como "data"
}
```

E pegue os dados com `getData()` (Não sou um programador Android, então não vou poder te ajudar muito nessa parte... rsrs)

```
// Coloque um break-point neste if e verifique se está entrando aqui com o APP fechado
if (remoteMessage.getData().get('title').equals("Entrega")) {
    showNotificacaoTeste(remoteMessage.getData().get('body'));
}
```

[Documentação: onMessageReceived](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive?hl=pt-br)

Comment: testei com o data , mas nao deu certo nao =/

Comment: Com o data a mensagem está passando pelo `onMessageReceived` com o app fechado?

Comment: Aparentemente não

Comment: Amanhã vou tentar com mais calma

Comment: Atualizei o código da resposta, quando conseguir testar me avise.

Answer (score 0):

Na criação da notificação vc deve chamar o alarm

```
private void showNotificacaoTeste(String body) {
    //Uri do som do alarm
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);//Pega o alarm padrão do sistema, pode ser personalizado aqui

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 1 ,new Intent(),PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT );
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
    builder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Entrega")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound);//Som é adicionado a notificação aqui

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(1,builder.build());
}
```

O que mudou foi só `builder.setSound(alarmSound);` onde som é adicionado a notificação aqui

Fonte https://stackoverflow.com/a/15855464/4395789